# Re-order stacked histplot in Python's seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use Python's `seaborn` library and the `histplot` function to create a stacked barplot.

Here an example of how my data and the plot look:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


group = np.repeat(['G1', 'G2'], 4)
value = np.array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4'])
percentage = np.array([20, 10, 40, 30, 50, 25, 20, 5])
stacked = pd.DataFrame({'Group':group, 'Value':value, 'Percentage':percentage})
    
sns.histplot(stacked, x = 'Group', hue = 'Value', weights = 'Percentage', multiple = 'stack', palette = 'colorblind', shrink = 0.75)
plt.legend(labels = stacked['Value'].unique()[::-1], bbox_to_anchor = (1, 1), fontsize = 8)
```

[image: this is how my current plot looks]

I simply want to **reverse the order of `Value`** so that the blue part (1) is on bottom and the dark orange part (4) in on top. I.e., it should be ordered the same way as it is in the legend and the colors should stay the same (1 = blue, 2 = light orange and so on). Somehow, I can't manage to create this.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is the goal to make it stacked from bottom to top in ascending order (with respect towards value), to reverse the coloring order, or both?

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly but I think both. the answer from @user1740577 below is pretty much what I want, just the y-axis still don't look that great in their plot in my opinion...

Comment: Are you looking for `hue_order`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `invert_yaxis` and set `yticks` from 0 to 100 like below:

```
axe = sns.histplot(stacked, x = 'Group', hue = 'Value', weights = 'Percentage', multiple = 'stack', palette = 'colorblind', shrink = 0.75)
plt.legend(labels = stacked['Value'].unique()[::-1], bbox_to_anchor = (1, 1), fontsize = 8)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,100,20), np.arange(100,0,-20))
axe.margins(y=0)
plt.show()
```

If you add these lines you get this output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, looks great! I used `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 20), np.arange(100, -1, -20))` to add a y-axis tick at 0. Still, I would have hoped there is an easier way than manually flipping and re-labeling the y-axis...